# DialogFragment in CustomView is causing memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-dialogfragment, leakcanary

I have a MainActivity which has a customView(DatePicker) in its layout. DatePicker customView has a button and a CustomDialogFragment. When the Button is clicked on the DatePicker it shows the CustomDialogFragment. App works fine but leakCanary shows a leak. Here is the code(Some code deleted for brevity)

MainActivity.class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        date_picker.calendarDialog = getCalendarDialog()
    }

    private fun getCalendarDialog(): CalendarDialog {
        return CalendarDialog()
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <com.example.testproject.customViews.DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </com.example.testproject.customViews.DatePicker>
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

DatePicker.class

```
class DatePicker : FrameLayout {
    var calendarDialog: CalendarDialog? = null
    init {
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.date_picker, this)
        open_calendar.setOnClickListener {
            calendarDialog?.show((context as MainActivity).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction(), "Calendar")
        }
    }
}
```

CalendarDialog.class

```
class CalendarDialog: DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context!!)
        builder.setView(view)
            .setMessage("This is a dummy message")
            .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which -> }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, which -> }

        return builder.create()
    }
}
```

HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
    ====================================
    1 APPLICATION LEAKS

```
References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.

1437 bytes retained by leaking objects
Signature: 1eb8b5c7c3fd403a9a6851729c4044c8a6ce7cf6
┬───
│ GC Root: System class
│
├─ android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager class
│    Leaking: NO (InputMethodManager↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
│    ↓ static InputMethodManager.sInstance
├─ android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager instance
│    Leaking: NO (DecorView↓ is not leaking and InputMethodManager is a singleton)
│    ↓ InputMethodManager.mNextServedView
├─ com.android.internal.policy.DecorView instance
│    Leaking: NO (LinearLayout↓ is not leaking and View attached)
│    mContext instance of com.android.internal.policy.DecorContext, wrapping activity com.example.testproject.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    Parent android.view.ViewRootImpl not a android.view.View
│    View#mParent is set
│    View#mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    ↓ DecorView.mContentRoot
├─ android.widget.LinearLayout instance
│    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking and View attached)
│    mContext instance of com.example.testproject.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    View.parent com.android.internal.policy.DecorView attached as well
│    View#mParent is set
│    View#mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    ↓ LinearLayout.mContext
├─ com.example.testproject.MainActivity instance
│    Leaking: NO (DatePicker↓ is not leaking and Activity#mDestroyed is false)
│    ↓ MainActivity._$_findViewCache
├─ java.util.HashMap instance
│    Leaking: NO (DatePicker↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ HashMap.table
├─ java.util.HashMap$Node[] array
│    Leaking: NO (DatePicker↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ HashMap$Node[].[0]
├─ java.util.HashMap$Node instance
│    Leaking: NO (DatePicker↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ HashMap$Node.value
├─ com.example.testproject.customViews.DatePicker instance
│    Leaking: NO (View attached)
│    mContext instance of com.example.testproject.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    View.parent androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout attached as well
│    View#mParent is set
│    View#mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
│    View.mID = R.id.date_picker
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    ↓ DatePicker.calendarDialog
│                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
╰→ com.example.testproject.customViews.CalendarDialog instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.example.testproject.customViews.CalendarDialog received Fragment#onDestroy() callback and Fragment#mFragmentManager is null)
​     key = e176896c-49c6-4b17-a21e-4a6ca7cde260
​     watchDurationMillis = 11213
​     retainedDurationMillis = 6208
​     key = f3a2f22a-c77f-4c8e-a281-d803d110acff
​     watchDurationMillis = 11214
====================================
0 LIBRARY LEAKS

Library Leaks are leaks coming from the Android Framework or Google libraries.
====================================
METADATA

Please include this in bug reports and Stack Overflow questions.

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 28
Build.MANUFACTURER: Google
LeakCanary version: 2.2
App process name: com.example.testproject
Analysis duration: 4191 ms
Heap dump file path: /data/user/0/com.example.testproject/files/leakcanary/2020-03-11_10-15-46_729.hprof
Heap dump timestamp: 1583936152876
====================================
```

These are the things I have tried so far with no luck.

1. I have tried initializing CalendarDialog at different places.
2. Create a listener in CalendarDialog class and make 'calendarDialog' instance null when the dialog is dismissed. And Few more..

Comment: There is no incorrect code in the classes above. Could you provide full classes code?

Comment: I don't have any more code. That is all.

Answer (score 2):

You can put CalendarDialog in a WeakReference, that way you do not have to explicitly set it to null through a callback. The garbage collector will automatically clean it up and you can avoid the memory leak.

For more information on WeakReference: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference

Answer (score 1):

When the CalendarDialog fragment is dismissed, that fragment is expected to be garbage collected. However here we can see that the DatePicker layout is keeping a reference to it, preventing it from being garbage collected. DatePicker is still attached, so it makes sense for it to still exist, but it should set its DatePicker.calendarDialog field to null when the dialog is dismissed.

Comment: I thought the same.I added a callBack to CalendarDialog and set the instance of CalendarDialog in DatePicker to null when dismissed is called. That didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Make CalenderDialog as the utility function

```
class CalendarDialog {

  fun onCreateDialog(context: Context): Dialog {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    builder
        .setMessage("This is a dummy message")
        .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which -> }
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, which -> }

    return builder.create()
  }
}
```

and

```
class DatePicker(context: Context, attr: AttributeSet) : FrameLayout(context, attr) {

  var calendarDialog: CalendarDialog? = null

  init {
    View.inflate(context, R.layout.date_picker, this)
    open_calendar.setOnClickListener {
        calendarDialog?.onCreateDialog(context)?.show()
    }
  }

  override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow()
    calendarDialog = null
    open_calendar.setOnClickListener(null)
  }
}
```

The activity has no idea that the dialog fragment exists in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar experience before. All I did was to change `supportFragmentManager` with `childFragmentManager`. So I suggest to change this:

```
calendarDialog?.show((context as MainActivity).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction(), "Calendar")
```

to this:

```
calendarDialog?.show((context as MainActivity).childFragmentManager.beginTransaction(), "Calendar")
```

Also, look for any other `supportFragmentManager` (if there is any).